# Mac OS Directory Services/LDAP user with local admin rights

Tags: macos, ldap, directoryservices

I've have several network based users (Mac OS X Directory Services). Some of them need local admin rights on their Mac OS X Workstations (10.6.4). They should be able to install software and to change system settings.

I added the users (i.e. /LDAPv3/server.domain.com/Users/harry) to the local (workstation's) admin group /Local/Default/Groups/admin but harry cannot change system settings for instance.

May someone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer :-):

I first tried to add the harry through dscl. But that did not succeed.

Following command did the trick for me:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -n /Local/Default/ -u YourLocalAdminUser -a YourLogin -t user admin
```

YourLogin must be in the search path, normally this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: To be clear, YourLogin is the user you are adding with admin privileges.

Comment: Had to remove the trailing `/` on the directory path, but other than that, this did the trick perfectly! Thanks!